# Show that the green function is satisfies the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

> Show that the given green's function below,
>
> $$g(x,s)=\begin{cases}
>  -\dfrac{\cos{ks}}{k}\sin{kx},\quad x\lt s\\
>  -\dfrac{\sin{ks}}{k}\cos{kx},\quad s\lt x\\ \end{cases}$$
>
> satisfies the ODE :
>
> $$u''+k^2u=f(x)$$

Here is my work :

We know, if we have a green's function

$$G(x,s)$$

Then,

$$u(x)=\int G(x,s)f(s)\,\mathbb ds$$

So, i was thinking about substituting this $u(x)$ when $x \lt s$ (btw, i doubt it) to the original equation, and i have:

$$\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left[\int -\dfrac{\cos{ks}}{k}\sin{kx}f(s)\,\mathbb ds\right]+k^2\left[\int -\dfrac{\cos{ks}}{k}\sin{kx}f(s)\,\mathbb ds\right]=f(x)
$$

What's next to do?

I don't think it will gives me true cz it has $f(s)$ instead of $f(x)$ there?

Or it could be, cz i have to substitute $s=x$ and ignore the negative sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the full solution formula
$\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\newcommand{\dd}{\,\mathbb d}$
$$
u(x)=-\cos(kx) \int_{-\infty}^x \dfrac{\sin(ks)}{k}f(s) \dd s - \dfrac{\sin(kx)}{k} \int_x^\infty \cos(ks)f(s) \dd s 
$$
This assumes that $f$ has either finite support or is falling fast enough. Then you can compute derivatives
\begin{align}
u'(x)&=\sin(kx)\int_{-\infty}^x \sin(ks)f(s) \dd s -\cos(kx)\dfrac{\sin(kx)}{k}f(x)\\&\qquad - \cos(kx) \int_x^\infty \cos(ks)f(s) \dd s + \dfrac{\sin(kx)}{k}\cos(kx)f(x) \\
&=\sin(kx)\int_{-\infty}^x \sin(ks)f(s) \dd s - \cos kx \int_x^\infty \cos(ks)f(s) \dd s\\[1em]
u''(x)&=k\cos(kx)\int_{-\infty}^x \sin(ks)f(s) \dd s + \sin(kx) \sin(kx)f(x)\\&\qquad + k\sin(kx)\int_x^\infty \cos(ks)f(s) \dd s +\cos(kx) \cos(kx)f(x)\\
&=-k^2u(x)+f(x)
\end{align}